# Setting up foreign keys with multiple has_one relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I'm setting up an app for posting items wanted/available/bartering.  I've got two main classes, Post and Item.

Each post contains an offered_item, a wanted_item, or both.  Here are my current definitions:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wanted_item, :class_name => 'Item', :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :offered_item, :class_name => 'Item', :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :location, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  attr_accessible :title, :description
end
```

**On to my question: How do I structure the foreign keys in the Items table such that I can tell which post  (and whether it's a wanted_item or offered_item)?**  Is this done in the migrations files or in the models?

As it currently sits, when I try a query like:

```
Post.find(:first).wanted_item
```

I get the following:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.post_id: SELECT 
>   "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."post_id" = 1 LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set conditions on associations, like so:

```
has_one :wanted_item, :class_name => 'Item', :conditions => ['kind = ?', 'wanted']
```

and add a `kind` column to `Item` (don't use "type", it's a reserved word).

EDIT: reading your post again, your `Item` table seems to be lacking the foreign key. In your migration file that creates your `Item` table, simply include `t.references :post` to have rails create a post_id foreign key column.